# Why does Claire tell Raffi he's "nine"?

Tags: dialogue, collateral-beauty

In the movie *Collateral Beauty*, in the following dialogue between Claire and Raffi, I can't understand why Claire calls Raffi "nine":

> Claire: "That was the worst thing I've ever done."
>
> Raffi: "That was the best thing I've ever done."
>
> Claire: "What was that thing you said about Einstein in there?"
>
> Raffi: "Einstein called time a stubbornly persistent illusion."
>
> Claire: "What's that even mean?"
>
> Raffi: "Time doesn't go from January to December, or from noon to
> midnight. You know, we all just make it that way in our heads."
>
> Claire: "That's absurd. Try telling that to a person who's an hour
> late to a wedding or was just sentenced to 20 years in jail."
>
> (SCOFFS)
>
> Raffi: "Or someone fighting a baby clock."
>
> Claire: "We really don't need to have this conversation, ever. Anyway,
> just... Yeah, wanted to say great job today."
>
> Raffi: "Just a stubborn illusion, Claire. You have all the time in the
> world."
>
> Claire: **"You're nine!"**
>
> Raffi: **"You're nine."**

Raffi isn't a 9 year old boy, so it's not about his age, I guess. What does it mean then?

Comment: Maybe she meant that Raffi had the mentality of a nine year old.  Maybe she meant that because of what Raffi is saying he is now number nine on her list of people to kill.

Comment: @M.A.Golding _Maybe she meant that because of what Raffi is saying he is now number nine on her list of people to kill._ - When did Raffi say that? And why 9? Why not any other number?

Comment: What you you mean by "When did Raffi say that?"?  Your question quotes several lines of dialog from Raffi that Claire responds to by saying that they don't need to have that conversation. And RAffi continues to talk about the subject.  That might be enough for Claire to jokingly or seriously threaten to kill Raffi.